# quitting xcode cocoa swift app

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I have written my first swift OS/X application in XCode 6. It all works except I cannot figure out how to exit the app.  I have a button to exit and the `ExitNow` function defined as follows:

```
@IBAction func ExitNow(sender: AnyObject) {
    // ???
}
```

I cannot figure out what the code would be.  By searching online I've found various options, but they were either in Objective C or too general for me to comprehend. I would appreciate an example which would behave the same way as `cmd-Q`.

Answer (score 91):

You should be able to just call [terminate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/terminate:) on the global `NSApp` object.

---

Swift 4 & 5:

```
@IBAction func ExitNow(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)
}
```

---

Swift 3:

```
@IBAction func ExitNow(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)
}
```

---

Swift 2:

```
@IBAction func ExitNow(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
}
```

Comment: This I tried and got the following error

NSApp.terminate(self)'terminate' is unavailale. APIs deprecated as of OS X 10.9 and earlier are unavailable in Swift.

Comment: Oops, apparently you can't use that with NSApp, sorry. I edited my answer so that it uses `NSApplication.sharedApplication()` instead. I also tested it real quick in a brand new OSX Swift project targeting 10.10 and it worked fine.

Comment: error in syntax --> for swift 3 solution ---> use if unravel identifier

Comment: As of Swift 4, it's `NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)`

Comment: If you terminate using this, then the app would not open again if you want to open it programmatically

Answer (score 17):

Or we could simply exit from the app like this:

```
@IBAction func ExitNow(sender: AnyObject) {    
    exit(0)
}
```

As a side note you can exit because of an error:

```
fatalError("reason for exiting")
```

Unconditionally prints a message and stops execution. iOS 8.1 and later.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 9.0 you might use NSApp.terminate(nil).